# Current flows in zener diode

Tags: diodes

so my professor told me that the current flows in this circuit is I=(VI-(Vzo+0.7) / R.
But as I learned earlier, it should be written as (VI-Vzo)/ (R+rz).
I didn't get it. Which is wright?

[image]

Comment: * I=(VI-(Vzo+0.7) / R.* That expression misses one ")". Instead of "learning all the formulas" learn **how** we derive these formulas. Once you master that, all your formulas will always be correct! *(VI-Vzo)/ (R+rz)* What is this "rz"?

Answer (score 1):

The first equation is correct.

The 0.7V comes from the 2nd zener diode which is forwards biased so becomes a standard diode.

The other diode is in reverse zener breakdown (becaues Vi >> Vz) so the total voltage across the two diodes is Vz + 0.7.

Now that you have the voltage on both sides of the resistor, the current through it is that voltage difference divided by R.

"Rz", presumably the zener resistance, isn't really a thing. Diodes are non-linear components and as such do not behave like resistors.

Comment: I fully understood that the Zener diode is non-linear and should not be treated like a resistor! got it! thank you so much